# why am getting different milliseconds value in compared to both (QTIme & QueryPerformanceCounter)

Tags: c++, qt, performancecounter, query-performance

my .h file

```
#ifndef ITime_H
#define ITime_H
#include <QDebug> 
#include <iostream>
#include <QtCore>
#include <windows.h>


class ITime 
{
public:
    ITime();
    ~ITime();
    void start();
    quint64 milli();
    quint64 elapsed();


public:

    QTime oStartTime;
    QTime oEndTime;

    LARGE_INTEGER ntime1,ntime2;
    LARGE_INTEGER freq;

};

#endif // ITime_H
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

my cpp  file

```
#include <QTime>
#include <QtCore>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

ITime::ITime()
{    
}

ITime::~ITime()
{   
}

void ITime::start()
{   
    oStartTime = QTime::currentTime(); 
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&ntime1);
}
quint64 ITime::milli()
{   
    quint64 milli =  oStartTime.msecsTo(oEndTime);
    return milli;
}

quint64 ITime::elapsed()
{   
    quint64 ntime = 0;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&ntime2);
    oEndTime = QTime::currentTime(); 
    ntime = (ntime2.QuadPart-ntime1.QuadPart)/(freq.QuadPart/1000000.0);
    double elapsedMilliseconds = elapsedTicks.QuadPart / (freq.QuadPart/                     1000.0);
qDebug() << "milli seconds by counter :" << elapsedMilliseconds ;

    return ntime;
}
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

my main file

```
#include "ITime.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    ITime time;
    time.start();
    qDebug() << "Start time" << time.oStartTime ;
    qDebug() << "differnce time in micro by counter" << time.elapsed() ;
    qDebug() << "differnce time in milli " << time.milli() ;
    qDebug() << "End time" << time.oEndTime ;

}
```

my output is like this

Start timeQTime("17:57:46") 
milli seconds by counter : 1.20633 
differnce time in micro by counter:  1206 
differnce time in milli by using QTime : 0 
End time QTime("17:57:46")

here, by considering the output 
microseconds is 1206 by counter    , it mean almost 1 milliseconds , but in output milliseconds is 0 by QTime  , so how can i get same difference in milli  & micro seconds

actually i want to know why the differece in time is coming in between QTime and counter

Comment: You are dealing with integers. `freq.QuadPart/1000000` will throw away precision that you probably want to retain. Potentially it is the same with the other division. I don't know whether the formula is correct, but the following would be safer provided that it doesn't overflow the numerator: `(1000000 * (ntime2.QuadPart-ntime1.QuadPart))/freq.QuadPart;`

Comment: If you can rely on windows 8 or later then there's built in functionality for combining real time with QPC called [GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706895(v=vs.85).aspx)). This gives accuracy of 0.1 microsecond increments which is the best you can get on Windows. As always with accurate time on windows, [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx) is a must read.

Comment: According to the docs of [`QTime::msecsTo()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#msecsTo): 1) it returns **signed** `int`; 2) it "can return 0 if either time is invalid" (can be checked with `QTime::isValid()`)

Comment: I don't think your usage of QTime in this case is correct. QTime only provides wall-clock time in millisecond precision, it's not designed to be a high resolution steady clock.

Comment: `std::chrono` is your friend. The steady clock uses the performance counter, is easier to write, and more portable.

Answer (score 0):

[`QueryPerformanceFrequency`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905(v=vs.85).aspx) provides the counter frequency in "counts per second". That means that whatever `QueryPerformanceCounter` returns, will be represented against the divisor that `QueryPerformanceFrequency` provided to begin with. In other words (assuming you can target a system that does arithmetic on `QuadPart` which is extremely likely)...

```
LARGE_INTEGER freq;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
LARGE_INTEGER startTicks;
QueryPerformanceCounter(&startTicks);
//Do work here
LARGE_INTEGER endTicks;
QueryPerformanceCounter(&endTicks);
LARGE_INTEGER elapsedTicks;
elapsedTicks.QuadPart = endTicks.QuadPart - startTicks.QuadPart;
double elapsedMicoseconds = elapsedTicks.QuadPart / (freq.QuadPart / 1000000.0);
double elapsedMilliseconds = elapsedTicks.QuadPart / (freq.QuadPart / 1000.0);
double elapsedSeconds = elapsedTicks.QuadPart / (double)freq.QuadPart;
```

... should answer your question. You can break that up any way that you see fit including truncating into a form such as `SS.MMMMM` (seconds and miliseconds).

Also note that you should only call `QueryPerformanceFrequency` once and save the result as it doesn't change between system boots and it is just a redundent call after the first one.